# How can I preserve the proposed commit message when a hook fails?

Tags: git, githooks

When I add a commit-msg hook which exits with 1 to indicate some error,
the original git commit message is gone/not used when I run git commit again.

Is there a way to retain the old commit message so that I do not have to 
enter the whole message again but just edit the old commit message instead?

Comment: I'm wondering about this too. You can immediately rescue your message from `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, but it would be nice if there's a way to retain the message when the last `git-commit` failed for whatever reason.

Comment: I wish this question had an answer. I'm looking for the same. For now, I am just showing a big WARNING for the user and suggesting him/her to use `git commit --amend` to edit the commit message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lost commit message from failed git commit-msg hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975103/lost-commit-message-from-failed-git-commit-msg-hook)

Comment: (Marking this one as the duplicate since the other question already had an answer, as per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/10095231)

Comment: @4ae1e1 If you're still looking for something more automatic, I posted a wrapper script in the duplicate above.

Comment: @ricardomenzer With the wrapper you also can more easily get away with making the hook actually fail the commit.

Comment: @kelvin I've been using [magit](https://magit.vc) as my git client for years now, where I simply `M-p` (`git-commit-prev-message`) in `git-commit` mode to bring back a previous message. No longer a problem for me :-)